# Make empty filed space

Tags: php, forms, extjs

I have this menu:

```
items:[      
{
    xtype: 'form',
    id: 'searchPanel',
    title: 'Search',
    collapsible: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    height: 210,
    buttonAlign: 'left',
    defaults: {
        width: 400,
        labelWidth: 120,
        allowBlank: true,
        enableKeyEvents: true        
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 2
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'txtFltrSiteName',
            fieldLabel: 'Site name or alias',
            id: 'txtFltrSiteName'
        },

        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'txtDiskCost',
            fieldLabel: 'Disk cost',
            id: 'txtDiskCost',
            style: 'margin-left: 100px;'
        },

        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'txtFltrProjectName',
            fieldLabel: 'Project name',
            id: 'txtFltrProjectName'
        },

       // many other fields
```

And chackboxes and text fields have diffirent width, so it looks ugly. 
**So the queston is:**
How to make empty `<td>` in this form?
For examle I want 6-2 items:

```
----------
| 1  | 1 |
| 2  | 2 |
| 3  |   |
| 4  |   |
|..etc...|
----------
```

Comment: If it were me I'd probably use a column layout for this and define the columnWidth as .5 so they were evenly spaced out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make hidden input.
like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'hidden',
    name: 'hidden1',
    id: 'hidden1'
},
```

This will make `<td>` column, but it'll be empty coz it'll be `hidden` input in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better one:

```
{
  xtype : 'label',
  text  : '',
  labelSeparator: ''
}
```